# Returning a datatable from a LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Basically I have an originating `DataTable` that has 1.5 million rows.  What I want to do is essentially group all those rows by `tc` and return sum of `tr` grouped by `tc` as another `DataTable`. Any help is welcomed!  The code below compiles by I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,System.Data.DataRow],<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Decimal]]'
>   to type

```
public static DataTable TSummerization()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Summerization Request");
    IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
    (IEnumerable<DataRow>)from b in Program.myTimetable.AsEnumerable()
                          group b by b.Field<string>("tc") into g
                          select new
                          {
                              tc = g.Key,
                              tr = g.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("tr"))
                          };

    return query.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

This question is not a duplicate.  Can someone show an example of how to actually return a DataTable without AsEnumerable instead of returning `IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>`

Comment: *DON'T* USE `AsEnumerable()`. That will load all 1.5M rows in memory instead of generating a SQL statement. If LINQ complains without it, fix the problem, don't try to cover it with `AsEnumerable()`

Comment: Try `return query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>()`

Comment: LINQ to what? Entity Framework? NH? Linq to SQL? You *don't* need the LINQ to Datatable extensions if you work with any one of the ORMs. You should be able to write `from b in ctx.myTable group b by b.tc into g select new { tc=g.Key, tr=g.Sum(x=>x.tr)};`

Comment: Is `myTimetable` a DataTable with 1.5M rows already loaded? That is a very big bug in its own right. *Don't* load everything in memory, let the database do it!

Comment: Why dont you use a datatabse?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Can you give a full example?  i'm not sure what you're trying to do with ctx

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos querying the table is to slow

Comment: What @PanagiotisKanavos is asking is..if your data is in a database, why are you loading all that data to a datatable to do a sql query when you can let the database do all that work?

Comment: `ctx` is the database context in EF. How and *why* did you load 1.5M rows? Even if you *do* want to get sums from all of them, it's a lot faster to send the query to the database. The query knows about indexes so it knows which rows to group and which fields to add. The datatable doesn't and will have to iterate over all rows to generate the sums.

Comment: @user6445891 no, querying a table is *not* slow. A bad query is slow. Querying without the proper indexes is slow. Add proper indexes, check the execution plan for any suspicious table scans. Use SQL Server's "Database Engine Tuning Advisor" for any missing indexes. In fact, SSMS itself will tell you if an index is missing when you select your query and hit Ctrl+L

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I allready don't want to get into a sql argument.  Using a TCP Channel C# application to house an in memory object is over 4.5 times faster to run a sum when the objects exceed 10 million.  I've already ran baseline tests.  I'm really trying to make the code more flexible at this point and I'm not very familiar with LINQ

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  select sum(tr),tc from myTable with there is an index on tc cannot get more efficient

Comment: @user6445891 but *is it used*? If `tc` isn't the first column, the index will *not* be used. As for 10M, that's a small number for a data warehouse. These days they run in the terabyte range

Comment: @user6445891 also note the many answers that get deleted *immediatelly*. You are asking about lighting a cigar sitting on a dynamite box. No-one is going to tell you how to do this until you get away from the box

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos huh...?  Look - I quick typed the query, which is irrelevant.  SQL 2014+ instituted In-Memory OLTP (In-Memory Optimization) for this very reason.  I don't have access to 2014.  Your analogy is really just a scarecrow argument.  At the end of the day, how do you return a DataTable from Linq query

Comment: As for the tests - did you include the time needed to *load* the data? Because scanning the entire table to return individual rows *is* the same as scanning all rows to calculate a group/sum, just more expensive on the network. Unless your database is starved for RAM and has to use tempdb. In which case, it would be better to add the same amount of RAM you use for your table to the server

Comment: @user6445891 in-memory OLTP has nothing at all to do with this. And no, no scarecrow. Just a DW developer talking. Now, columnstore indexes, already available in 2012 would make this 100x times faster as they compress and group the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Loading the data is irrelevant when it's kept in sync.  Ugh i'm done with this part of the conversation.  You see a snippet of code and a very minor statement on the project and you pretend to know the whole thing.

Comment: @user6445891 excluding the load time is actually a bad benchmark. And I do know the whole thing, it's my day job to produce such sums from millions of rows in seconds. That's why I use columnstore indexes btw

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Okay, explain to me how come I can run the same query against a DataTable at a much faster rate using TCP Sever hosting a MarshalByRefObject call.  It's simple - the data is already housed in memory and not on disk.  You're saying the indexes are much faster and not needed, however with that many rows and an index on one column still has to load it to memory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos seconds are to slow... I don't understand what you don't get about that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  decimal (and numeric) with precision greater than 18 digits   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492153%28v=sql.110%29.aspx    Just stop

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Also good job marking this as duplicate - all your posts links return `IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>` which is incorrect.   Good job ruining a post.

Comment: OK, then I won't tell you about how just an array would be faster, or how using PLINQ would be a *lot* faster

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos PLINQ would be faster.  You're telling me that parallelism would be faster!?!  That's earth shaking!  How do you do it?  <sarc>  Stop being a holier than thou coder.  And even with PLINQ that doesn't solve the above question.  I'd have the same problem

Comment: I must agree,i don't think this is an exact duplicate. Although it won't be very efficient,try this. It's not very efficient,but maybe helps you.First, don't cast your query to `IEnumerable<DataRow>` use just `var`. Then try this code: `var a=query.ToList();
            DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
            dtReturn.Columns.Add("tc");
            dtReturn.Columns.Add("tr", typeof(Decimal));
            foreach (var result in a)
            {
                dtReturn.Rows.Add(new object[] { result.tc, result.tr });
            }`

Comment: @Pikoh  Thanks Pikoh, I agree this would work but I wanted to use LINQ